# How to write this type of data to csv

Tags: python-3.x

im a noobie in python. I want to get some data from csv with pandas and after write a new csv file with extra data in format 
"type";"currency";"amount";"comment"
"type1";"currency1";"amount1";"comment1"
etc

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

  req=pd.read_csv('/Users/user/web/python/Bookcopy.csv')
  type="type"
  comment = "2week"
  i=0
  while i<3:
  Currency = req['Currency'].values[i] 
  ReqAmount = req['Request'].values[i] 
  r = round(ReqAmount,-1)
  i+=1
  data =[type,Currency,r,comment]
  #print(data)

csv_file = open('data2.csv', 'w')
with csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(data)

print("DONE")
```

writer.writerows(data)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have multiple things to criticize here. I hope it doesn't come across mean, but rather educational. While your code would work regardless of those points, it is good coding style to follow them.

- Variables should not start with a capital letter. `Currency` and `ReqAmount` should be `currency` and `reqAmount`.
- Don't use keywords for variable names. `type` is a python keyword.
- Make sure your formatting doesn't get destroyed when posting here. Especially for python, which relies on tab formatting. Read here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

That said, let me try to go through your code and give you tips and tricks:

- Don't run code in python directly. Always use the `main()` method. It's just better coding style.
- When looping, don't use the `i=0; while i<3; i+=1` construct, rather use `for i in range(3)`. While it works, it is not very pythonic and a lot harder to read.
- Never assume anything that cannot be guaranteed in your code. In this case, you assume that the csv-file has at least 3 lines, otherwise your program would crash. Instead, read the number of lines from the csv file, with `len(req)`.
- `data =[type,Currency,r,comment]` keeps overwriting your `data` variable. You could either *append* to `data` and then write everything to the output file at the end, or directly write to the output file in every iteration.
- Don't use `open` to create a variable (except absolutely necessary). Instead, use `open` in a `with` statement. This ensures that the file will get closed properly. I have seen that you do use the `with` statement, nonetheless you usually use it like `with open(...) as variable_name:`.
- CSV files usually start with the column names. Therefore you should write the column names before you write data.
- I won't fix that, because it will change the appearance of the program completely, but normally, don't mix different libraries. If you use `pandas` for csv reading, also use it for writing. If you use the `csv` library for writing, also use it for reading. While it isn't *wrong* to mix them, it is bad style and creates more dependencies than would be necessary.

I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do, so I just guess and hope it goes in the right direction.

When fixing all those points, you might have something like that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

def main():
    req=pd.read_csv('/Users/user/web/python/Bookcopy.csv')
    transferType = "type"
    comment = "2week"

    with open('data2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(["type","currency","amount","comment"])

        for i in range(len(req)):
            currency = req['Currency'].values[i] 
            reqAmount = req['Request'].values[i] 
            r = round(reqAmount,-1)
            data = [transferType,currency,r,comment]
            #print(data)

            writer.writerow(data)

    print("DONE")

# Whenever you run a program, __name__ will be set to '__main__' in the initial
# script. This makes it easier later when you work with multiple code files.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all tips that you give to me. Your code work fully how i imagined it !

Comment: Now i have another problem that i cant write data like this - "transferType";"currency";"r";"comment" . Ive tried - comment = ' "2week" ' and etc but it write in file """2week""" not "2week"

Comment: You can't. If you write csv, you have to respect the csv file format. If you have a string in csv, you don't need the `"`. If you have the character `"` in that string, you have to _escape_ it, like in many other languages, and the escaped version of `"` is `"""`. While it might be legal to put `"` around all strings in csv, it is unnecessary, and therefore the `csv` library doesn't do it. Leave these things to the library, and it will be compatible with everything that can read csv.